# How to interpret these two equalities involving 2-norm?

Tags: normed-spaces

What is the difference between $$\Vert x+y \Vert_2^2 $$ and  $$\Vert x+y \Vert_2 $$ Can we write

$$\Vert x+y \Vert_2  \stackrel{?}{=} \sqrt{\Vert x+y \Vert_2^2} \tag{*}$$

Moreover, when does (1) and (2) hold true

$$\Vert x+y \Vert_2^2 = \Vert x \Vert_2^2+ \Vert y \Vert_2^2 \tag{1}$$

$$\Vert x+y \Vert_2 = \Vert x \Vert_2+ \Vert y \Vert_2 \tag{2}$$

In my understanding, (1) is true when $x \perp y$. Is this true for (2) as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\Vert x \Vert_2^2 = (\Vert x \Vert_2)^2$$

---

$$\Vert x+y \Vert_2^2 = \Vert x \Vert_2^2+ \Vert y \Vert_2^2 \tag{1}$$

This holds true for orthogonal vectors, yes.

$$\Vert x+y \Vert_2 = \Vert x \Vert_2+ \Vert y \Vert_2 \tag{2}$$

This holds true for parallel vectors. It's a special case of the triangle equality.

Comment: I was thinking that (2) will hold true when $x \perp y$ and $x^Tx=y^Ty=1$

Comment: @NAASI No. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: Does it mean that $(*)$ is not true? But that is not the case as you stated it as a fact in the start of your answer. So how come (1) holds for orthogonal vectors whereas (2) is true for parallel? Its the relationship between the two $(*)$ that is confusing me

Comment: (*) is true. But (1) is a generalization of the pythagorean theorem and (2) is a special case of the triangle inequality. And to have a really simple example: While $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$ is true, $3+4=5$ clearly isn't, if you consider a rectangular triangle that has two orthogonal sides (vectors) with lengths 3 and 4.